# Picture Box - Tool Tip Text ( .NET 2.0 - C# )

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to have a Tool Tip Text for a PictureBox. If so, please give me a solution.

I am working in .NET 2.0 with C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ToolTip component to your form and then set the "ToolTip on myToolTip" property of the PictureBox